# Remove the 'category' url for one category type

Tags: functions, categories

We have categories on our posts such as:

https://www.example.com/category/announcement/

https://www.example.com/category/blog/

https://www.example.com/category/events/

I'd like the blog to have a url of -> https://www.example.com/blog/

Can anyone show me how this is done using functions.php?

I've tried adjusting in the Settings and Yoast SEO but it removes the 'category' in all the category types.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want this: **www.exp.com/blog** Just create a page and put the slug as blog! then go to the settings > Reading, there you should put a page for your blog posts simply choose the page that you created on the previous step named blog.
after that, all your posts will be visible on the **www.exp.com/blog**.

Comment: thank you! that makes sense :)